# What caused the error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make GUI that reverses the user input but something is wrong

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def reverse(s):
    s=U.get()
    return s[::-1]

root=Tk(className="Reverse your text")

la=Label(root, text="Enter text to reverse")
la.pack()

U=Entry(root,textvariable=s)
U.pack()

BT=Button(root, text="reverse", command=reverse(s))
BT.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

```
Error:   U=Entry(root,textvariable=s)
         NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: That error seems pretty self-explanatory. You're trying to use the variable `s` before you define variable `s`. What do you think `textvariable=s` is doing, when `s` doesn't exist?

Comment: You can't really _return_ an object(s) when you use the function as a button command, you should instead modify object(s).

Answer (score 2):

- `def reverse(s):` should not have an `s` if you don't intend to pass any arguments to the function. Likewise for `command=reverse(s)`
- `U=Entry(root,textvariable=s)` does not need a textvariable if you're just going to access the Entry's value directly with `.get`. And anyway, you can't use `s` here, because you never assigned a StringVar object to `s` to begin with.
- The value returned by `return s[::-1]` will not be visible in any way to the user. If you want to show the reversed string, you need to print it or insert it into the entry, or similar.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def reverse():
    s=U.get()
    U.delete(0, END)
    U.insert(0,s[::-1])

root=Tk(className="Reverse your text")

la=Label(root, text="Enter text to reverse")
la.pack()

U=Entry(root)
U.pack()

BT=Button(root, text="reverse", command=reverse)
BT.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]